# how to get event of item changing in snap ScrollView?

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is my ScrollView which works like page view(Tab View Content). and changes the content by snap style:

```
              <ScrollView
                    ref={(scr) => this._scrollView = scr}
                    decelerationRate={0}
                    snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').width}
                    snapToAlignment={"center"}
                    pagingEnabled
                    horizontal
                >
```

now every thing works pretty good but i need an event that runs when the page  changed completely. can any one help me how to getting that please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use function ***onMomentumScrollEnd*** (called when the scrollView glides to a stop)